# if $X^2 +AX+B=0$ has a rational root, prove it is an integer.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

If $x^2 + Ax +B =0$ has a rational root, prove it is an integer.

I don't even know where to start on this problem. I've had it on my white board for about a week and keep looking at it, but can't see any part of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [rational root theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem) says that if $$p(x)=a_nx^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\ldots+a_1x+a_0$$ is a polynomial with integer coefficients, and $\frac{p}q$ is a rational root of $p(x)$ written as a quotient of integers in lowest terms, then $p$ is a divisor of $a_0$, and $q$ is a divisor of $a_n$. When $a_n=1$, as it is in your case, this implies that any rational root must in fact be an integer. I suspect that you’re supposed to do mor than quote a theorem, however.

The full rational root theorem isn’t actually hard to prove — there’s an elementary proof at the link — but you can use the same idea directly on your problem. Suppose that

$$\left(\frac{p}q\right)^2+A\left(\frac{p}q\right)+B=0\;.$$

Multiply through by $q$ to get $\dfrac{p^2}q+Ap+Bq=0$, or $\dfrac{p^2}q=-
Ap-Bq$. The righthand side is now an integer, so the lefthand side must be an integer as well, which means that $q$ is a divisor of $p^2$. If $\dfrac{p}q$ was in lowest terms, what does this tell you about $q$?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that $A,B$ are integers then $x^{2}+Ax+B$ has a rational root implies the root, $r$, takes the form $r=\frac{p}{q}$ where $p$ divides $B$ and $q$ divies $1$ (the leading coefficient). This means $q=\pm1$.

Comment: Are you assuming $A$ and $B$ are integers?

Comment: Yes I'm assuming the coefficients are integers. Thank you very much for your edit.

Comment: I realized that. I was in the process of updating my answer. Thank you too Brandon.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the equation $x^2+ax+b=0$, where $a$ and $b$ are **integers**.

Let $r$ be a rational solution of our equation. Then $r=\frac{m}{m}$, where $m$ and $n$ are integers.  Without loss of generality we may assume that $m$ and $n$ are relatively prime, and that $n\ge 1$.

Substitute $\frac{m}{n}$ for $x$ in the equation $x^2+ax+b=0$. We get 
$$\frac{m^2}{n^2}+a\frac{m}{n}+b=0,$$
 or equivalently
$$m^2 +amn+bn^2=0.$$
Note that $n$ divides $amn+bn^2$. It follows that $n$ divides $m^2$. We will show that $n=1$.

Suppose to the contrary that $n\gt 1$. Then $n$ has a prime factor $p$. Since $n$ divides $n^2$, we conclude that $p$ divides $n^2$. It follows, since $p$ is prime, that $p$ divides $n$.

Thus $m$ and $n$ have a common factor $p$ greater than $1$. This contradicts the fact that $m$ and $n$ are relatively prime.

We conclude that $n=1$. It follows that $\frac{m}{n}$ is an integer.